# Can punched-in seed phrase on steel plate be read by airport security x-ray?

Tags: security, seed

If I put a steel plate with seed phrase in bag and it goes through TSA's x-ray machines at the airport, am I at risk of them being able to read the words?

Answer (score 2):

High resolution x-ray cameras of the type used for baggage scanning would likely be able to read stamped metal.  For an example, [this Chinese security manufacturer](https://www.safeagle.com/news/948-can-the-x-ray-machine-be-able-to-see-the-metal-in-the-metal-bottle) shows an example image where you can pretty easily make out a lot of detail.  Looking at their product line shows they have a variety of x-ray technology that would be capable of producing high resolution images from metal contained in your bags.

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112736/34975) answer over on the Physics Stack Exchange site says:

> The X ray detectors work by sending a beam of X rays through the stuff they are probing. The higher the density, the more X rays gets absorbed, the less one detects on the other side. In fact, we are not measuring density, but integrating it along the line of sight; the total mass the ray had to go through.

So assuming the stamping slightly modifies the density of the metal or the thickness of the metal, presumably anything written on a metal surface might be read.

Multisig wallets are a way around this particular security concern in that you only have an individual piece of the private key required to spend coins.  [This answer has some details about that](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/120417/10658).  Check the list of questions tagged with [multi-signature](/questions/tagged/multi-signature) for even more info.